# When using the method while, it throws an error Name error

Tags: python, python-3.x

When using the method while, it throws an error Name error...This error  "while running:
NameError: name 'running' is not defined".Help me please!Thanks!

```
number=25
running:True

while running:

guess=int(input('Is your number:'))
  
if  guess == number:
print('Yea!')
      running=False
elif guess > number:
print('No')
else:
print('No')
```

Comment: running=True. replace your ':' with '='

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `:` with `=`

```
running=True
```

It will work for you

```
number=25
running=True

while running:
    guess=int(input('Is your number:'))
    if  guess == number: 
        print('Yea!')
        running=False
    elif guess > number:
        print('No')
    else:
        print('No')
```

Answer (score 1):

`running` is a variable, so define it with:

```
running = True
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments you need to set `running = True`, also your indentation will raise further errors. You want to do

```py
number=25
running=True

while running:

    guess=int(input('Is your number:'))
  
    if  guess == number:
        print('Yea!')
        running=False
    elif guess > number:
        print('No')
    else:
        print('No')
```